# simply change IP after installation on server minimal

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I'm using CentOS 6.5 minimal.

Is there any way to display a dialog to change the IP after login? In other words, some way of entering a command with a dialog to change the IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run either `system-config-network` or `setup`. I prefer `setup` since you can access most everything from this dialog (Firewall, Network, etc.).

#### Example

```
$ sudo setup
```

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

[image: ss #3]

[image: ss #4]

#### Installation

```
$ sudo yum install setuptool system-config-network-tui
```

Comment: You can set this during the installation instead. That's typically where I'll do it via the UI (GUI or Text UI - aka TUI) during installation of CentOS on the system. Are you asking how can you run this so that the GUI is automatically launched when someone/root logs in?

Comment: yes and without restarting network service

Comment: @motaz - running `setup` will take care of restarting the network for you automatically. Are you trying to make this so it's automated for someone else or yourself?

Comment: for someone else who doesn't know anything about commands

Comment: restarting network service not running automatically

Comment: @motaz - strange that must of changed from CentOS 5, you can run the command like this to get the network to restart afterwards: `setup ; service network restart`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is:

```
system-config-network
```